# Error al ejecutar: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hola al ejecutar el proyecto con el que ando después de solventar diversos problemas, ahora nos ejecuta este error..

> No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'EntityFramework, Version 4.4.0.0 ni una de sus dependencias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podías echar una mano gracias

Comment: Hola Dunia, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Puedes **cambiar** la foto por el texto del codigo y del error?  Mira tambien [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la calidad de la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Ese código lo has cogido de otro sitio? Parece que no encuentra la librería. ¿seguro que tienes EF instalado? Si no lo tienes, entonces descárgate el NuGet package. De lo contrario ejecuta un update con el comando NuGet para obtener la version que aparece en el error.

Comment: Si esta instalado, de hecho volvimos a instalar el paquete con actualizaciones y si ya esta realizado

Comment: Asegurate de que en todos los proyectos donde se referencia esa librería apunten a la misma versión 4.4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Haz un respaldo del proyecto e intenta instalar el paquete de EF que no se encuentra. Me extrañó el número de versión 4.4 pero ahora mirando [este blog](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/unicorn-myths-debunked-entity-framework.html) parece que se trata de la versión 5 y aparece como 4.4 porque tienes MS-Framework 4.

> There is no such thing as Entity Framework 4.4!
>
> The 4.4 comes from the assembly version of EntityFramework.dll when
>   you install EntityFramework 5.0 into a project that targets .NET
>   Framework 4.0. This is merely a side effect of how the runtime loads
>   and binds to assemblies, and in no way reflects the version of the
>   product.

En Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Console, ejecuta esto:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0.0
```

Si ya tienes una versión instalada puedes hacer el Update o eliminar la que tienes e instalar una nueva. Un problema al instalar esa versión también aparece discutido [aquí, en este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488014/install-ef-4-4-0-0/28937345).

Comment: si gracias ya lo he solucionado ahora ya nos arroja otro pero con el sql gracias

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso habilité las app en 32 bits en la configuración avanzada de tu pool.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]